# Relevancy score based on term order and text index

Tags: solr

I have documents like this:

```
(1) 3825051 3835055 A 14 051
(2) 3833013 3834034 A 2 013
(3) 4537002 4637021 A 38 002
(4) 4537002 4537002M A 38 002
(5) 4537002 4537002M A 381 002
```

My Solr query is: `q=+"a" AND +"38"`

The datatype config:

```
<fieldType name="text_wildcard" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I need the documents based on the text index and the order of the terms "a" and "38" --> (3),(4),(5),(1),(2) Now the result is in the order like above.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some experimentation, but you could index your content in several separate fields: your current field, one field where you don't use the EdgeNGramFilterFactory, and possibly more fields where you do use the EdgeNGramFilterFactory with longer and longer minGramSize. Then, query against all fields and possibly experiment with boosts (e.g. field1NoEdgeNGram^5 field2EdgeNGram2^4 field3EdgeNGram3^3, etc). I think the effect will be what you're looking for - give higher rank to matches that correspond to a longest prefix in your data.

Comment: The boosts are the solution. Thank you very much

Comment: I my case the only 2 fields are necessary.